# How do you search across multiple mercurial repositories

Tags: mercurial

I'm setting up multiple Mercurial repositories for all of our different projects, probably close to 50. Is there a way to search across multiple repos for a specific file or string? For example, say that a database column is renamed, how would I search each repository for any reference to the old column name? I know that I can do this for each repository individually, but if you've got 50 repositories, that can be quite time consuming?

If it's not possible, are there any best practices then for structuring your repositories to minimize this pain?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible -- repositories are entirely independent.

If you wanted to set up a global search one way to do it would be to push all your 50 repositories into a single repository that can be searched.  Something like this:

```
hg init everything
for therepo in /path/to/repos/* ; do
   hg -R everything pull -f $therepo
done
```

Then you can search in `everything`.   You could keep everything current using a cron job or `changegroup` hooks on your other repos that do a push to everything.

Comment: It's actually possible (see below), but I agree with Ry4an that if you're going to be doing this operation frequently, you should keep local copies of all 50 repositories.

Comment: @leoger had an answer but he deleted it.  It didn't work, but it was a good try and probably the fault of bad help text in the first place.

Comment: @Ry4an, Honestly, it was more the fault of my not reading the help text thoroughly enough, but thanks for helping to create a positive environment on SO for those who are well intentioned yet occasionally sloppy. :)

Comment: Heh, no worries. I'd've not mentioned it at all except for my foolish assumptions about above or below two years ago. :)